# Colormap list options in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, color

I'm trying to draw a room illuminated by a light, so I reached this far, but I don't know what are my options for the colormap

```
\documentclass[border=0.2cm]{standalone}
 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps}
 
\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}
 
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.25]
\begin{axis}[
    axis equal image,
    grid = both,
    minor tick num = 2,
    xlabel = {$x$},
    ylabel = {$y$},
    zlabel = {$z$},
    major grid style = {draw = lightgray},
    minor grid style = {draw = lightgray!25},
    legend cell align={left},
    ymin = -1, ymax = 1,
    xmin = -1, xmax = 1,
    scale = 3,
    zmin = 0, zmax = 1.1,
    z buffer = sort,
]
 
% top of the cone
\addplot3[
    surf,
    shader = interp,
    samples = 50,
    samples y = 5,
    domain = 0:2*pi,
    domain y = 0:1,
    opacity = 0.65,
    colormap/yellowwhite,
]
(
    {(cos(deg(x)))*(1-y)},
    {(sin(deg(x)))*(1-y)},
    {y}
);
 

 
\end{axis}
 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's all explained in [the manual](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots):

> Chapter 4: *The Reference*
> → *Markers, Linestyles, (Background) Colors and Colormaps*
> → *Color Maps*

This is on page 195 of the manual labelled “Revision 1.18.1 (2021/05/15)”. For instance, you can define a color map and give it a name:

```
\pgfplotsset{
  colormap={my colormap}{rgb=(0,0,1) color=(black) rgb255=(238,140,238)},
}
```

then use it with `colormap name=my colormap`.

```
\documentclass[border=0.2cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{
  compat=1.18,
  colormap={my colormap}{rgb=(0,0,1) color=(black) rgb255=(238,140,238)},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.25]
\begin{axis}[
    axis equal image,
    grid = both,
    minor tick num = 2,
    xlabel = {$x$},
    ylabel = {$y$},
    zlabel = {$z$},
    major grid style = {draw = lightgray},
    minor grid style = {draw = lightgray!25},
    legend cell align={left},
    ymin = -1, ymax = 1,
    xmin = -1, xmax = 1,
    scale = 3,
    zmin = 0, zmax = 1.1,
    z buffer = sort,
]

\addplot3[
    surf,
    shader = interp,
    samples = 50,
    samples y = 5,
    domain = 0:2*pi,
    domain y = 0:1,
    opacity = 0.65,
    colormap name=my colormap,
  ]
  (
      {(cos(deg(x)))*(1-y)},
      {(sin(deg(x)))*(1-y)},
      {y}
  );
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

What you want may look like this:

```
\pgfplotsset{
  colormap={yellowwhite}{rgb=(1,1,0) rgb=(1,1,0.8) rgb=(1,1,1)},
}

...

\addplot3[..., colormap name=yellowwhite] (...); ...
```

[image]

The predefined color maps, when `\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps}` is *not* used, are `viridis` and `hot` (the default). If you load the `pgfplots` `colormaps` library, many more color maps are readily available: `autumn`, `bled`, `bright`, `bone`, `cold`, `copper`, `copper2`, `earth`, etc.: see [the manual](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots) under *Related Libraries* → *Colormaps* (page 430 in my version).

Example with the `hsv2` colormap. Note the `\pgfplotsset{colormap/hsv2}` in order to load it; *then* it can be used with `colormap name=hsv2` (well, you could use `colormap/hsv2` in the `\addplot3` optional argument without doing the `\pgfplotsset{colormap/hsv2}` at all, but this would be less efficient in case you use this colormap several times in the same document).

```
\documentclass[border=0.2cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\pgfplotsset{colormap/hsv2} % <-------- this loads the 'hsv2' color map

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.25]
\begin{axis}[
    axis equal image,
    grid = both,
    minor tick num = 2,
    xlabel = {$x$},
    ylabel = {$y$},
    zlabel = {$z$},
    major grid style = {draw = lightgray},
    minor grid style = {draw = lightgray!25},
    legend cell align={left},
    ymin = -1, ymax = 1,
    xmin = -1, xmax = 1,
    scale = 3,
    zmin = 0, zmax = 1.1,
    z buffer = sort,
]

\addplot3[
    surf,
    shader = interp,
    samples = 50,
    samples y = 5,
    domain = 0:2*pi,
    domain y = 0:1,
    opacity = 0.65,
    % or 'colormap/hsv2', but this is less efficient
    colormap name=hsv2,
  ]
  (
      {(cos(deg(x)))*(1-y)},
      {(sin(deg(x)))*(1-y)},
      {y}
  );

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]